# Как вернуть отфильтрованые сериализованные данные?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Хочу отправлять гет запрос для фильтровки общего кверисета по дате.

Вот что я имею на данный момент:

views.py

```
class RecognationObjectViewSet(GenericViewSet, ListModelMixin):
    queryset = RecognizedObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecognationObjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(created_datetime__lte=timezone.now())

    @action(methods=["GET"], detail=False, serializer_class=RecognationObjectFilteredSerializer,
            url_name='get-caler-set', url_path='filr-set')
    def get_calen_set(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.GET)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            result = serializer.save()
            prn(result)
            serializer_result = RecognationObjectSerializer(result)
            return Response(serializer_result.data)
```

serialazers.py

```
class RecognationObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RecognizedObject
        fields = ['user', 'created_datetime', 'user_photo']


class RecognationObjectFilteredSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    from_date = serializers.CharField()
    to = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = RecognizedObject
        fields = ["from_date", "to"]

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        from_date = self.validated_data['from_date']
        to = self.validated_data['to']
        result = RecognizedObject.objects.filter(created_datetime__gte=from_date, created_datetime__lte=to)
        return result
```

и такой вот запрос 
http://localhost:8000/project/rec-objects/filr-set/?from_date=2018-07-22&to=2020-07-22

Вот такой Responce это возвращает

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "user": null,
    "user_photo": null
}
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так

Answer (score 0):

В views.py нужно поменять

```
serializer_result = RecognationObjectSerializer(result, many=True)
```

И будет работать