# TypeError: 'Category' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

TypeError: 'Category' object is not iterable. Пытаюсь реализовать слагирование

***TRACEBACK***

````
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 199, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 46, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 760, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 678, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 678, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 529, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 678, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
TypeError: 'Category' object is not iterable```
````

**Модели Product, Category. Отношение M2M.**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    parental_category = models.ManyToManyField('self', 
                                                blank=True,
                                                verbose_name='Категория-родитель',
                                                )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True,
                            verbose_name='Название')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, 
                                 related_name='category',
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 verbose_name='Категория',
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Serializers**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id','name','slug',
                  'category']

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name', 'parental_category']
```

**views**

```
class ProductList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        category = self.kwargs['category_slug']
        if category is not None:
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__name=category)
        return queryset
```

**urls**

````
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:category_slug>/', ProductList.as_view(), name='product_list_by_category'),
]```
````

Comment: а можете показать шаблон в котором выводите этот queryset

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Такого шаблона нет. Обычный локалхост DRF

Comment: попробуйте serializer_class = ProductSerializer заменить на  serializer_class = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin qyeryset is not defined

Comment: def get_queryset(self,**kwargs) еще в функции поменяйте.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin К сожалению ошибка с необьявленным qyeryset осталась

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093382/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5 попробуйте сделать как тут, вроде вы хотите примерно тоже самое

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в serializers.py 
ProductSerializer

Суть ошибки заключалась в том, что я для M2One reference использовал many=True

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    sale = SaleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    attributes = AttributeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id','name', 'price','sale',
                  'manufacturer', 'category', 'attributes']
```